React 18 - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'matches')
I am getting the following error when testing using window.matchMedia. This runs fine in production and locally, it is only an issue during testing.
I am using React 18 with vite.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'matches') 
It is suggested in the jest docs to add the following to my setupTests.js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: vi.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: vi.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: vi.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: vi.fn(),
    removeEventListener: vi.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: vi.fn(),
  })),
})

This does not appear to work.

The solution was to add the following to my setupTests.js instead,
global.matchMedia = global.matchMedia || function(query) {
  return {
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: vi.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: vi.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: vi.fn(),
    removeEventListener: vi.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: vi.fn(),
  }
}



It looks like you're setting up the mock for window.matchMedia correctly, but there are a couple of things you can check and tweak to make it work.
Make sure that your setupTests.js is properly set up to be included in the Jest testing environment.
module.exports = { setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setupTests.js'] };

Also since you mentioned vi.fn(), you're likely using Vite's vitest instead of Jest. In this case, ensure that you have correctly imported vi from vitest
import { vi } from 'vitest';

